# how does the set of inverses of complex numbers become a circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Can someone show me how this equality is achieved?

$$\left\{\frac{1}{\frac1p - ir}: r\in \mathbb{R}\right\}\cup \{0\} = \left\{w\in \mathbb{C}: |w-\frac{p}{2}|=\frac{p}{2}\right\}$$

I'll really appreciate any help!

Comment: $p$ is real.?..

Comment: What if p is a positive integer?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left| \frac{1}{1/p-ir}-\frac{p}{2} \right|
=\left| \frac{p}{1-ipr}-\frac{p}{2} \right|
=\frac{|p|}{2} \left| \frac{2}{1-ipr}-1 \right| \\
=\frac{|p|}{2} \left| \frac{2-1+ipr}{1-ipr} \right|
=\frac{|p|}{2} \left| \frac{1+ipr}{1-ipr} \right|
$$ If $p$ is real, $$
=\frac{p}{2} \cdot 1 = \frac{p}{2}.
$$ This is not true if $p$ is not real. Indeed, if $pr$ is any complex number, then its distance after +90 degree rotation (times $i$) with 1, need not be the same with that of its distance after -90 degree rotation (times $-i$).

To show converse inclusion, $$
\mathfrak{Re} 1/ \big[ \frac{p}{2} (1 +e^{i\theta}) \big]
=\frac{2}{p} \mathfrak{Re} \big[  1/(1 +e^{i\theta}) \big] \\
=\frac{2}{p} \mathfrak{Re} \big[  (1 -e^{i\theta})/2 \big]
=\frac{2}{p} \cdot \frac{1}{2} =\frac{1}{p}.
$$ As desired.

Comment: What if p is a positive integer?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
z\in\left\{\frac{1}{\frac1p - ir}: r\in \mathbb{R}\right\}\cup \{0\}
&\iff&
\forall r\in \mathbb{R}: z=\frac{p}{1-ipr}\\
&\iff&
\forall r\in \mathbb{R}: \frac{2}{p}\left(z-\frac{p}{2}\right)=\frac{1+ipr}{1-ipr}\\
&\iff&
\Big|z-\frac{p}{2}\Big|=\frac{p}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
because for **real** $p$, the map $w=\dfrac{1+ipr}{1-ipr}$ maps imaginary axis to unit circle.

Comment: What happens when p is a positive integer?

Comment: @J.B. Realy $p>0$ and with $p$ positive integer nothing happens. $pr\in\mathbb{R}$ works here.